# Equation where the unkown is the operation itself

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-algebras

I was wondering. We have normal equations, where the unknown is a number. And we have differential equations, where the unknown is a function.

Are there equations where the unknown is the operation itself?

For example, $5  ¿  2 = 7$

Solving the equation gives $¿ = Addition$

Comment: Your question can be rephrased as: find a function $f(x,y)$ such that $f(5,2)=7$; keep in mind that an operation is also a function.

Comment: “Addition” is only one possible operation. Here’s another operation: $a*b = ab-3$. That’s a binary operation on the integers, and $5*2 = 7$. As you can guess, there are infinitely many possible answers. The question is as indeterminate in this form as “what is the next number in the sequence?” problems are (answer: any! I can produce a rule that will give whatever number you want as the “next” number)

Comment: These things are called "functional equations", although the example you give does not have a unique solution, there are uncountably many other possibilities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation